# Failed to get complex Object

Tags: angular

I need to get value from my Arrray and use it like input, I have complex Array ( means it has 2 Object) I can't read the second Object, i tried many ways but I failed.

**This is May array:**
[image]

**Failed Code :**
First try:

```
this.dataArray[1]
```

Second try:

```
this.dataArray[0][1]
```

**JSON**

```
0: Array(2)
0:
customData: "I need to eat"
date: "2021-08-09T21:22:30.641+0000"
idnotifRelpay: 1
message: "Your call has been taken into account, we are dealing with your demands."
patientNotificationId: 1
receiverId: 251
state: "DONE"
title: "REPLAY"
type: "FOOD"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: 250
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

**My code :**

```
this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getNotificationsReplaysByPatientNotificationId"));
      this.Datalist = JSON.stringify(this.data)
      console.log('------------------------')

      console.log(this.data)

      console.log('------------------------')

      let values = Object.keys(this.data).map(key => this.data[key]);
      for(let i in values){
        this.dataArray.push(values[i][0])
        console.log(this.dataArray)
      }

       
   if(JSON.stringify(this.data) == "{}"){
     this.emptydata = false
   }
```

Comment: Can you share your json on https://jsonblob.com/

Comment: Done can u check please

Comment: Can you share the link of your json?

Comment: I failed to save but i edit the post u can find all data

Answer (score 0):

The array in your screenshot looks like this:

```
[
  [
    { type: "FOOD", state: "DONE", ... },
    250
  ]
]
```

It is an array that contains exactly one element: Another array with two elements. The inner array's first element is an object, and the second object is the number 250.

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but there is no second object here.

Comment: is an Object i'm just reading the id here, but i get 2 different Object that's way they are separeted

Comment: In your first picture, the array you're showing does _not_ have an object in the second position. The number you have highlighted is the _entire_ value stored in the second position of the array. Perhaps you are accidentally building the array by doing something like `array.push(item.id)` instead of `array.push(item)`?

Comment: yes, beacause i'm just reading the id, if i read the entire object i will get somthing like the fisrt , but in my case i don't need the whol object that's way i'm just reading the id

Comment: I guess it's just not clear to me what you're trying to do. You said, "I can't read the second Object," so it sounded like you're trying to read the second object from this array that contains one object and one number.

Comment: i'm trying to read the second object wich containe the number 250

Comment: At the very bottom of your screenshot, it says "length: 1", your outer array only has one element in it. There is no second object in that array.

Comment: look u have Array0 contains first object with index 0 and second with index 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235807/discussion-between-stephen-jennings-and-lili).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with your 2nd try and it seems to be working fine. Make sure that `this.dataArray` is referring to the right array object. Other than that, it looks good to me :)

```js
var dataArray = [
     [
          {
            customData: "I need to eat",
            date: "2021-08-09T21:22:30.641+0000",
            idnotifRelpay: 1,
            message: "Your call has been taken into account, we are dealing with your demands.",
            patientNotificationId: 1,
            receiverId: 251,
            state: "DONE",
            title: "REPLAY",
            type: "FOOD",
          },
          250
     ]
];

console.log(dataArray[0][1]);
```

Comment: When i try, i get this : undefined

Comment: This means that the context of `this` is not pointing to the right object under which your `dataArray` lies. Can you show me the code so I can have a look?

Comment: I don't know but i can read the firstt Object, i edited the post can u check please

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense but why there is a `[0]` in this line `this.dataArray.push(values[i][0])` - Does this exclude any indexes other than 0?

Comment: can't read  data without this [0] may be this is the problem !

Comment: Yes, it could be. I can only debug if I have the code with the required data.

Comment: can u tell me how please, the data is from my database !

Comment: Try making a fiddle and instead of the local storage line, put the actual data there.

Comment: sorry can get it "fiddle"

Comment: Put your code here and share the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/